# How to send a mail when a mail id itself contains spaces?

Tags: java, email, jar, message, whitespace

How can i send a mail to a mail id that contains some spaces in it.
For eg. for a group mail id we have mail id as `DL-BLR F1 A2@company.com`

I tried in java using javax  jars but it says illegal whitespace error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an e-mail address that contains spaces you have to pass `false` for the `strict` parameter in the `InternetAddress` constructor, like this:

```
new InternetAddress("DL-BLR F1 A2@company.com", false);
```

This will skip some strict checks for RFC822 (including white spaces).

Answer (score -1):

you should try `st.replaceAll("\\s","")` it iwll replace all the spaces containing in string

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the next one?

```
"DL-BLR F1 A2"@company.com
```